# Azure Cognitive Services REST API URL returns 404 error in postman

Tags: rest, postman, azure-cognitive-services

I am having trouble accessing the following URL in postman (getting 404 error)

```
https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze
```

The URL was taken form Microsoft's own reference guide which I was able to test on their site:
https://australiaeast.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1/operations/5ed8c9843c2794cbb1a96291

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more details on your implementation? at least show your postman request so that we can ensure you are doing the right thing

Comment: Hi - I ended up resolving the issue by adding some missing headers to postman. Thanks @NicolasR

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone else that may face this issue, there are two headers that are required during POST /invoice/analyze as [described in the API reference](https://australiaeast.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1/operations/5ed8c9843c2794cbb1a96291)

1. `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` - This can be found in Azure portal after adding the "Form Recognizer" resource to your subscription
2. `Content-Type` - This depends on how you plan to post the invoice.

Here is a sample that I tried in Powershell

```
$myApiKey = "<Your key from Azure Portal>";
$myEndpoint = "<Your endpoint from Azure Portal>";

# Post the invoice image/pdf that you want cognitive services to analyze
$resp1 = Invoke-WebRequest `
  -Method Post `
  -Uri "$myEndpoint/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze" `
  -Headers @{ "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = $myApiKey; "Content-Type" = "application/json" } `
  -Body "{ 'source' : 'https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/raw/main/sdk/formrecognizer/Azure.AI.FormRecognizer/tests/samples/trainingFiles/Form_2.jpg' }" `

# Response header contains a url to get status and results of the operation
$opUrl = $resp1.Headers.'Operation-Location'

# Form recognizer may take a few seconds to complete analysis.  Loop and sleep for it to complete.
$status = "";
$resp2 = {};
Do
{
  $resp2 = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method Get `
    -Uri $opUrl `
    -Headers @{ "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = $myApiKey };

  $extractedInvoice = $resp2.Content | ConvertFrom-Json;

  $status = $extractedInvoice.status;
  if (($status -eq "running") -or ($status -eq "notStarted")) {
    Write-Host("Waiting for operation to comlete.  Sleeping for 10 seconds...");
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10;
  }
} While(($status -eq "running") -or ($status -eq "notStarted"));

$resp2.Content;
```